# Issue with SMS permissions

Tags: android, permissions, sms

this is my problem.
I need to write an app that sends an SMS at a specific time. At that moment the user can be away from the phone.

All the examples I've read and tried about SMS permissions have the effect to seek authorization to the user through pop-up (which says that the operation may charge a cost, etc.). As said before, the user can be away from the phone, so without user authorization the SMS can't be sent at the desired time.

Is there a way to get the authorization before and avoid to re-ask at the sending moment?

The permission declared in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

The SMS send is

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
smsMgr.sendTextMessage(Number, null, "txt", sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

You need to get permission at run time for android 6+. do this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegisterActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SM);
                    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegisterActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SM}, 1);
                    } else {
                        sendSMS();
                    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSMS();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```